# Syntax for the node command

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

Look at the two diagrams at the top of page 50 and the diagram at the top of page 220 in the manual at the following web site.
  http://mirrors.rit.edu/CTAN/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf
I have two questions about these diagrams.

For the diagram on page 50, here is the code.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

[place/.style={circle,draw=blue!50,fill=blue!20,thick},
transition/.style={rectangle,draw=black!50,fill=black!20,thick}]
\node at (0,2) [place] {};
\node at (0,1) [place] {};
\node at (0,0) [place] {};
\node at (1,1)[transition] {};
\node at(-1,1)[transition] {};

\end{tikzpicture}
```

For the diagram on page 220, here is the code.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw

(0,0) node[inner sep=0pt,draw] {tight}
(0cm,2em) node[inner sep=5pt,draw] {loose}
(0cm,4em) node[fill=yellow!80!black] {default};

\end{tikzpicture}
```

On page 50, it seems to me that variables "place" and "transition are being declared. What is the sytax for the `/.style` command?  I could have written

```
\node at (0,2) [circle,draw=blue!50,fill=blue!20,thick] {}
```

instead of

```
\node at (0,2) [place] {};  .
```

Is that right?

When does one use `node` as was used on page 220 and when does one use `\node` as on page 50?

On page 220, why does TikZ draw a rectangle about the given text?

I have three questions about the syntax for the code on page 50.

- The rectangle is drawn with `black!50`.  Is there a `black50`?
- Why is there an exclamation point?
- To what is `thick` referring?

Comment: `\node` is a shortcut for `\path node`. Hopefully this would answer one of your questions. The exclamation point is the syntax used by package `xcolor` (also used by tikz) to declare "mixings" of colors. In this case it is a mix of 50% black (and 50% white which is the default when the second colour is omitted). `thick` is the line width.

Comment: All the [options] for tikz are actually calls to \pgfkeys (or \pgfkeysvalueof) with different prefixes attached.

Comment: Answer to first question is 'yes'. Styles are a convenience and help keep formatting consistent. `thick` is the thickness of the lines. If you pass `draw` to the node, `tikz` draws the box around it which is rectangular by default. Too many questions for one question!

Answer (score 8):

In a nutshell, `<name>/.style` syntax is a container of other styles or codes that are called in the order of declaration.

This is the instance of the more general `key=value` system and it is part of the powerful `pgfkeys` library which you can read up in the same manual under libraries section.

So to your first question, yes that would be equivalent instead of calling the `place` style.

---

If you only want to place a node on a path, it is kind of tedious to write everytime `\path node` instead `\node` is defined which is a shorthand. But in case you have other path constructing commands then you use `node`, for example,

```
\draw (0,0) node[draw] {a} -- (1,1) node {b};
```

As you can see from this first node has a rectangle and the second doesn't because we supplied `draw` key to the node in the first node. Every node has a shape which you can draw or not (unless we define a new node with no background but that's not relevant now). You can also fill that shape, example

```
\node[fill=yellow,draw=red] {A};
```

So if you supply colors to these commands they draw or fill the value of the key.

---

TikZ uses `xcolor` package to define and use colors. Color mixing is done via `!` and you can use more than two colors. If you omit the mix colors white is used by default. Here, `black!50` is equal to mix black and white equally. The number between 0 and 100 selects `x` percent you take the left hand side and mix it with `100-x` with the right hand side (well at least you can take it as a simple mental shortcut. Color models are tricky business). Examples;

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \fill[blue!20!yellow!60!red] (2,0) rectangle (3,1);
    \fill[blue!20!yellow!60] (1,0) rectangle (2,1);    %  = (blue!20!yellow)!60!white
    \fill[blue!20!!60] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);          %  = (blue!20!white)!60!white
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

---

The drawing can have different line widths, and TikZ defines shortcuts for mostly used line width arguments as follows,

```
\tikzset{ultra thin /.style=line width=0.1pt,
         very thin/.style  =line width=0.2pt,
         thin/.style       =line width=0.4pt, %<= default
         semithick/.style  =line width=0.6pt,
         thick/.style      =line width=0.8pt,
         very thick/.style =line width=1.2pt,
         ultra thick/.style=line width=1.6pt
}
```

When you use `thick` on a path or a node together with `draw` the drawing is done using a pen with the line width of 0.8 pt.